# How to implement bulk update in MongoDb using multiple filters using c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection EmployeeDetails. The collection has 4 fields. I have filter with first three fields. I want to update ($set) if matching data found else insert (.SetOnInsert {upsert}); however in bulk.

```
EmpName:
EmpCompany:
EmpDesignation:
EmpSalary:
```

I would like to update EmpSalary on the basis of other fields. Also, filter data will be sent in bulk. Is it possible to so w/o a foreach loop.

I have tried the followed code:

```
foreach( var filterData in filterDataArrayList)
{
         var loadData = Builders<EmployeeModel>.Update
         .SetOnInsert(x=>x.EmpSalary , Salary)
         .SetOnInsert(x=>x.EmpName , Name)
         .SetOnInsert(x=>x.EmpCompany , Company)
         .SetOnInsert(x=>x.EmpDesignation , Designation)

var insertResult = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(
x=>x.EmpName == filterData.Name, x=>x.EmpCompany=filterData.Company, x=>x.EmpDesignation = filterData.Designation  ), loadData,
new UpdateOptions() {IsUpsert=true});

if(loadData.upsertId==null && loadData.matchedCount==1)
   {
      var updateData = Builders<EmployeeModel>.Update
         .Set(x=>x.EmpSalary , Salary)
      
      var updateResult = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(
      x=>x.EmpName == filterData.Name, x.EmpCompany=filterData.Company, x.EmpDesignation =filterData.Designation  ), updateData)

   }
```

This code works fine. I want to eliminate foreach loop for filter data. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("d");
        var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("c");

        coll.BulkWrite(new[]
        {
            new UpdateOneModel<BsonDocument>(
                "{ whatever1 : 1 }",
                new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument>()
                    .SetOnInsert("field1", 1)
                    .SetOnInsert("field2", 2)),
            new UpdateOneModel<BsonDocument>(
                "{ whatever2 : 1 }",
                new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument>()
                    .SetOnInsert("field21", 1)
                    .SetOnInsert("field22", 2))
                {
                    IsUpsert = true
                }
        });
```

This example is just to show how it can be done, you can use a typed/more complex way as in your example too

Comment: here you added 2 filters, but if we have a foreach loop, where we have have 3 filters, then how will this work.

Comment: I've added 2 different bulk requests (updateone in this case). Each request is independent. if you need 3 requests, then you should add a new request to the bulkWriteModels collection. However I don't understand what you want to do, your above code is not compiled.

Comment: I want to update documents in a collection based on filterData. If data is present, then update it i.e., update 'salary' ; if not present, insert all the details. The issue is, I am sending data in bulk, and applying filter in for loop and then upserting.

Comment: @pratyaksh So does replacing your loop with write models in a bulk write not solve your problem? Or is there something else you're not telling us?